# Wrong PHP.ini value is being loaded on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I use amazon EC2 instance.
I had an issue with PHP upload directory & i got this message on error_log :

```
[Mon May 27 21:25:26 2013] [error] [client xxx.96.169.198] Can't find a temporary directory: Internal error  [500, #20014]
[Mon May 27 21:26:13 2013] [error] [client xxx.96.169.198] The state report gatherer could not be created.  [500, #20014]
```

So i wanted to fix it by trying to set the "upload_tmp_dir" to "/opt/phptmp/" on the php.ini file. (this directory exists and i have chmod it to 777)

I have searched all php.ini file

```
[mybox@mybox /]# find -name php.ini
./etc/php.ini
```

And there is only 1.

I edited the upload_tmp_dir value and uploaded modified php.ini, stopped httpd, and started it.

But it seems it still didn't work. And i got additional issue, which is the APC configuration which is written on the php.ini is not loaded properly by PHP.
For example on the php.ini you can see that i set "apc.shm_size" to "512M"
But when you visit the APC info page (apc.php) the SHM size is only 32M.

(here are some lines from my php.ini)

```
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_size = 512M
apc.slam_defense = 0
apc.stat=0
apc.enable_cli = 1
apc.user_entries_hint = 16384
```

And from the PHP Info result, it seems the loaded php.ini is correct

```
Loaded Configuration File ----- /etc/php.ini
```

Anyone has suggestion how to fix this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does the directory exist and does php have permission to access it?

Comment: If you refer to "/opt/phptmp/", yes it exists and i have chmod it to 777. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Are you by chance running php in an fcgi configuration? or as an apache module?

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't look like a php error. This is thrown by your webserver. Check your (nginx?) configuration.

Concerning APC, you probably have an additional file `/etc/php.d/apc.ini` which overwrites the `php.ini` configuration

Comment: I only have 1 php.ini. But i have resolved my question. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i got no available disk space, so when i uploaded the php.ini with winscp, the file size is 0.
That's why the APC value is being read in wrong way.
And that solves the temp directory too.
What i did was deleting some unused log files.